# I tried updating the php in my laragon but I got this

Tags: php, laragon

https://forum.laragon.org/topic/166/tutorial-how-to-add-another-php-version, I tried doing this because I want to update my php to the latest version of php 7.3.

[image]

Now I got that error

Comment: you can ask this question  on https://forum.laragon.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Laragon, adding another PHP version is very easy. Here's how to add **`PHP 7.3`**

1. Download PHP: 
   http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/

In this case we download:
https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.3.0-Win32-VC15-x64.zip

---

2. Extract the downloaded to: `{LARAGON_ROOT}\bin\php\php-7.3.0-Win32-VC15-x64`

   C:\laragon
   -- bin
      ---- php
         -------- php-7.3.0-Win32-VC15-x64
         -------- .............

---

3. Select the new version at: Laragon **Menu > PHP > Version > php-7.3.0-Win32-VC15-x64**

Very easy huh. That's all!

Please be noticed about PHP Version (so you can add new extensions properly)
- `x64` means 64-bit
- `x86` means 32-bit
- `nts` means Non Thread Safe

---

**If something's wrong, please check and install correspond VC Redist (VC11, VC14, VC15...)**

Comment: Your PHP Version (php-7.3.0-Win32-VC15-x64)
& Apache Version (httpd-2.4.27-win64-VC14)
are not compatible!

----------------------------------------
Please make sure PHP and Apache are both:
- x86 (win32) or x64 (win64)
- Same VC (VC11, VC14, VC15...)
 Hey bud, I got this

Comment: Wrong directory structure:
C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.37-win64-VC15\Apache24\conf

Should be:
C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.37-win64-VC15\conf

Comment: Service Apache can not start. Reason: 

Unknown. Please check Apache log file

Comment: Hey buddy any possible fixes on this one.

Comment: What the hell dude, I already reinstalled and installed VC14 then I get this, what the heck? Your computer is missing some Visual C++ packages. Install "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" (VC14) may fix the problem

Comment: Current version of laragon is 4.0.4. What's your Laragon version?

Comment: Mine is 3.4.0 180809

Comment: You can upgrade to the latest version: https://forum.laragon.org/topic/1232/tutorial-how-to-upgrade-to-laragon-4-x-from-former-versions-laragon-3-x

Comment: As VC14 and VC15 can be exchanged each other, Laragon 4 will not show the warning about VC mismatch.